# Comparing multiple rows in dataframe to single row by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like below:

```
user       email                  day_diff  

tom        tommy@email.com         -10
tom        thomas@email.com        -2
tom        tom@email.com            3
bob        bob123@email.com        -11
bob        bob123@email.com         1
bob        bobby@email.com          2
alice      alice@email.com          4
Mary       mary@email.com          -5
```

What I am looking to do is for each user take every email where day_diff is positive and the first record where day_diff is negative but closest to 0. Then compare those values and if any of them are different, in a new column the value would 'yes' and if they are all the same the value would be 'no'

So for tom I would take the email where day_diff is 3, tom@email.com, since it's the only positive day_diff and compare it to thomas@email.com. Since it is different the new column for every row for tom would be 'yes'

For bob I would take the emails where day_diff is 1 and 2 and compare it to -11. Since the email at 2 and -11 are different, the new column value would be 'yes'.

If a user only has one row and the day_diff is positive, the new column value is 'yes' If the user only has emails where day_diff is negative, the new column value is 'no'

Any help would be appreciated. I've been spinning in circles trying to figure this out.

The output would look like

```
user       email                  day_diff    email_change

tom        tommy@email.com         -10        yes
tom        thomas@email.com        -2         yes
tom        tom@email.com            3         yes
bob        bob123@email.com        -11        yes
bob        bob123@email.com         1         yes
bob        bobby@email.com          2         yes
alice      alice@email.com          4         yes
Mary       mary@email.com          -5         no
```

Comment: You should show the desired output and all code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I suggest :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"user": ["tom", "tom", "tom", "bob", "bob", "bob", "alice", "mary"],
                   "email": ["tommy@email.com", "thomas@email.com", "tom@email.com", "bob123@email.com",
                             "bob123@email.com", " bobby@email.com", "alice@email.com", "mary@email.com"],
                   "day_dif": [-10, -2, 3, -11, 1, 2, 4, -5]})

# Treat case where no duplicates
df["dup"] = df["user"].duplicated(keep=False)
df["output"] = np.select([(df["dup"] == False) & (df["day_dif"] > 0), 
                          (df["dup"] == False) & (df["day_dif"] < 0)],
    ["yes", "no"], default=np.NaN)

# Treat duplicates
temp = df.loc[df["dup"], :]
temp = temp.copy()
temp["neg"] = np.where(temp["day_dif"] < 0, temp["day_dif"], np.NaN)
idx = temp.groupby("user")["neg"].nlargest(1).reset_index().level_1
# Create grouping variable that will help us make comparison
temp["pos"] = np.where(temp.index.isin(idx), 1,(temp["day_dif"] > 0) * 1)

groups = (temp.groupby(['user', "pos"])["email"].apply(list).reset_index()
              .sort_values(["user", "pos"]))
# compare all email in list by user and group pos
groups["output"] = groups["email"].apply(lambda x: all(w == x[0] for w in x))
# put on same line value for pos = 0 and pos = 1 for each user
groups["temp"] = groups["output"].shift(periods=-1)

# Apply your rules
groups["output"] = np.select([(groups.pos == 1) & (groups["output"] == False),
                              (groups.pos == 0) & (groups["temp"] == False)],
    ["yes", "yes"], default="no")
# reunite duplicates and non duplicates in one dataframe
new_df = pd.merge(df.loc[:, ["user", "email", "day_dif", "output"]],
                  groups[["user", "email", "output"]].explode(column="email"), 
                  on=["user", "email"], how="outer")
new_df["output"] = np.where(new_df["output_y"].isnull(), 
                            new_df["output_x"], new_df["output_y"])
new_df = new_df.drop(columns=["output_x", "output_y"]).drop_duplicates()
```

And the output is:

```
   user             email  day_dif output
0    tom   tommy@email.com      -10    yes
1    tom  thomas@email.com       -2    yes
2    tom     tom@email.com        3    yes
3    bob  bob123@email.com      -11    yes
5    bob  bob123@email.com        1    yes
7    bob   bobby@email.com        2    yes
8  alice   alice@email.com        4    yes
9   mary    mary@email.com       -5     no
```

Comment: I'm good until I get to the merge statement with explode. When I run it on my dataset I get the following error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-3326578153059991681.py", line 333, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-3326578153059991681.py", line 331, in <module>
    exec(code)

Comment: Perhaps I missed something from your actual data. Your `groups` DataFrame should have a column `email` where in each line you have list of emails and this is what you `explode`. `User` and `output` should be simple columns of dtype str. Is that what you have ?